# error: an enclosing instance that contains Note.JSONSerializer is required

Tags: java, json

```
    public NoteAdapter(){

        mSerializer = new Note.JSONSerializer("NoteToself.json", MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());

        try {
            noteList = mSerializer.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            noteList = new ArrayList<Note>();
            Log.e("Error loading notes: ", "", e);
        }

    }
```

**i don't know why it get an error, please help....**
getting trouble to fix:

```
mSerializer = new Note.JSONSerializer("NoteToself.json", MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Post your error log.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually a Java language error - nothing related to android.

I do not know where the class `Note.JSONSerializer` comes from. But I guess the class `JSONSerializer` is declared as an inner class of the class `Node`.
Have a look at the class `Node` to see if there is a method to create a new `Note.JSONSerializer` object.